# congestion avoidance on tcpgraph

Tags: tcp, wireshark, congestion-control

I'm trying to understand congestion avoidance on a realistic tcpgraph. I already looked up graphs of congestion avoidance, but they don't really align with mine. I know that congestion avoidance happens when the line goes from exponential to linear. I have an image of a tcpgraph from wireshark when I simulated 100% and 0% packet loss during a 10 MB download. I wish I could zoom in more into those areas where it plateaued. Do the circled areas count as "congestion avoidance"?

[image]